The correct way to simulate binary outcome data for logistic regression?
I am trying to conduct a simulation study that involves 3 covariates and a binary outcome based on the three covariates. What I did is to simulate three continuous variable x1,x2,x3 based on normal distribution, and assign coefficients $gamma$ for each of these covariates. Then I use function $exp(x^T\gamma)/(1+exp(x^T\gamma))$ to generate the value for $\pi$, and then generate binary outcome using binomial distribution based on $\pi$. My task is to test if using glm() in R with family "binomial" can give good estimation for the coefficient. However, the estimated coefficient is not very close to the true coefficient. However, I don't think this should happen if my data simulation process is correct.
I have attached my code in R. The reason I use logistic model without interception is because I didn't assume interception when generating t.
r <- c(0.33,3.75,2.82)
# specifying x when there's no correlation

x1 <- rnorm(500,1,1)
x2 <- rnorm(500,2,1)
x3 <- rnorm(500,5,1)

df2 <- data.frame(x1=x1,x2=x2,x3=x3)
x <- as.matrix(df2)

df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(l = x %*% r,
         p = 1/(1+l),
         t = rbinom(n(),1,t))

coef_corr_2 <- glm(t ~ x1+x2+x3-1,data=df2,family="binomial") %>% coef()

The estimated coefficient values are
> glm(t ~ x1+x2+x3-1,data=df2,family="binomial") %>% coef()
          x1           x2           x3 
-0.008725804 -0.022818767  0.083695370 

which is so far off from the true value.
I am wondering if I have done anything wrong at the data generation stage? I wish someone can spot the problems in my code or my line of reasoning, which really is just with such simple generation process the glm() should give a very good estimation of the coefficient.

I think there's something wrong with the code you've posted. You do t = rbinom(n(), 1, t) but you haven't previously defined t, so this won't run. It is presumably something else so that t is somehow generated based on x1, x2 and x3?

p = 1/(1+l) is wrong. You should use p = 1/(1+exp(-l)) or p = plogis(l).

@BenBolker Yes I saw that now, what I had in mind was exp(x^T\gamma)/(1+exp(x^T\gamma)). I don't know why I didn't spot this mistake at first...

My Example
When I have to do this, I prefer to do it this way:
set.seed(42)

n <- 10000

x1 = rnorm(n)
x2 = rnorm(n)
x3 = rnorm(n)
z = 0 + 1 * x1 + 2 * x2 + 3 * x3
p = 1 / (1 + exp(-z))
y = rbinom(n, 1, p)

data = data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3)

glm(y ~ -1 + x1 + x2 + x3, data = data, family = "binomial") |>
  coef()
#>       x1       x2       x3 
#> 1.000824 2.002293 3.005233

Created on 2024-04-16 with reprex v2.1.0
Your Code with Edits
Here is your version with 3 main edits:

replaced t with p: rbinom(n(),1,t) => rbinom(n(), 1, p)
corrected inverse-link function: 1/(1+l) => 1 / (1 + exp(-l))
increased sample size to get better estimates and removed predictor means: i.e., rnorm(500,5,1) => rnorm(10000)

library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)

r <- c(0.33, 3.75, 2.82)

x1 <- rnorm(10000)
x2 <- rnorm(10000)
x3 <- rnorm(10000)

df2 <- data.frame(x1, x2, x3)
x <- as.matrix(df2)

df2 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(
    l = x %*% r,
    p = 1 / (1 + exp(-l)),
    t = rbinom(n(), 1, p)
  )

glm(t ~ x1 + x2 + x3 -1, data = df2, family = "binomial") %>% 
  coef()
#>        x1        x2        x3 
#> 0.3416015 3.7593506 2.7905506

Created on 2024-04-17 with reprex v2.1.0
Note
As Ben suggested, remember to set.seed(42) to get reproducible output.

this fixes the OP's two problems (using t instead of p in rbinom, using the wrong inverse-link function)

@BenBolker I see that now. Question: is rescaling needed somewhere because setting means for the normals produces values for p that are always nearly 1.

Thank you so much for the reply! I didn't realized that I made stupid mistake in both p and y ... the 1/(1+l) definitely was what I had in mind.
I used
df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(l = x %*% r,
         p = 1/(1+exp(-l)),
         t = rbinom(n(),1,p))

coef_corr_2 <- glm(t ~ -1+x1+x2+x3,data=df2,family="binomial") %>% coef()

used the same setting for x1,x2,x3 as yours, the estimation is still slightly different. Do you have any thought on why is this the case?

Did you set.seed(42) ?

I haven't looked, but my quick guess is that the simulated mean values on the log-odds scale are large enough that the probabilities are all near 1, leading to a very unbalanced sample and poor power
